# I forgot my passwowd and my administrative account will not reset (password recovery)?

Tags: password-recovery

I am trying to find someone that knows how to work the 14.04 Password Recovery.  I have tried a million ways can someone please help me with a walk-through that actually makes sense?

I have tried to mount and remount and add new password through command prompt I have used the "Standard way" and I don't know everything seems to do what it should but I think I am doing something wrong.  I basically just need to know the way to do a password recovery without being able to access admin account prior.  I changed the password and have no idea what it is because I was very tied when doing so would be awesome to get the appropriate and most efficient way to do recovery for password in a form that I can actually understand

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain exactly what happened, what you did, what you tried, how it failed. What do you mean by your "account has been reset"?

Answer (score 0):

You have to boot from your Ubuntu Live CD, choosing “Try Ubuntu without any change to your computer” from the boot menu.

Once the system boots, open up a new Terminal and then type in the following command:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

This command is used to tell what device name the hard drive is using, "**hint**: The entry with * before"

I assume its sda1 for the rest

Now you’ll need to create a directory to mount the hard drive on. Since we’re actually booting off the live cd, the directory doesn’t really get created anywhere.

```
sudo mkdir /media/sda1
```

The next command will mount the hard drive in the /media/sda1 folder.

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /media/sda1
```

Now it’s time for the command that actually does the magic: chroot. This command is used to open up a shell with a different root directory than the current shell is using, and we’ll pass in the folder where we mounted the hard drive.

```
sudo chroot /media/sda1
```

Now you should be able to use the passwd command to change your user account’s password, and it will be applied to the hard drive since we are using chroot.

```
passwd USERNAME
```

Note that you’ll have to type your username after the passwd command in order to change the right password.

Now you should be able to reboot your system and log yourself in with your new password.

Comment: please mark this question as [duplicate](http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password) instead of writing another answer